# BigQuerySource on Date-Partitioned Tables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a set of date partitioned tables `employee_wages_<date>` and wanted to read a few of the columns using data-flow. Some thing on the lines of (python example)

```
beam.io.Read('ReadNameAndTotalSalary',
  beam.io.BigQuerySource(query='SELECT user_name, sum(salary) as total_salary FROM  `project_id.dataset_id.employee_salary_*` group by 1'))
```

The query work fine on google big query but I get and error saying invalid table name when I run the pipeline. Maybe I am doing some thing really stupid or is it not possible to use glob (*) within df?

Comment: The query is processed by BigQuery, not by Dataflow - Dataflow merely imports its results into the pipeline. Are you able to successfully execute the same query manually from the BigQuery UI?

Comment: This query looks like it's using Standard SQL, and dataflow is likely using Legacy SQL by default.

Comment: @Mosha... agreed and does data flow support non-legacy (standard) sql yet?

Comment: @jkff: yup, it does work

Comment: try starting the query with "#StandardSQL\nSELECT user_name..." so the query can run as a standard sql query without further configuration steps

Comment: The code should be fine to run however when run in BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner I end up getting Error: Message: Query text specifies use_legacy_sql:false, while API options specify:true HTTP Code: 400. So no game....

Comment: Have you had any success using the new `.withStandardSQL()` method mentioned in the the recent [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-java)?  If not, what errors do you get or how is the new method unfeasible?

Comment: Is it available in python/eclipse plugin?

Comment: As far as the release notes indicate, this is only for the **Dataflow Java SDK**.  The **[Dataflow Python SDK release notes](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-python)** show no addition of Standard SQL BQ support yet.

Answer (score 1):

Dataflow does not (yet) support BigQuery Standard SQL which you are using in your query. One workaround would be to prepend the query text with #StandardSQL, which will instruct BigQuery that the following query uses Standard SQL, i.e.

```
beam.io.Read('ReadNameAndTotalSalary',
  beam.io.BigQuerySource(query='#StandardSQL\nSELECT user_name, sum(salary) as total_salary FROM  `project_id.dataset_id.employee_salary_*` group by 1'))
```

(I think \n works as newline in Python, but I am no Python programmer)

**Update:** Dataflow SDK for Java 1.8.0 (which was released today), introduced usingStandardSql setting, but it is not in python SDK (yet).

Comment: The code should be fine to run however when run in **BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner** I end up getting `Error: Message: Query text specifies use_legacy_sql:false, while API options specify:true HTTP Code: 400`. So no game....